# Pipe doesn't work with semaphores

Tags: c, pipe, semaphore

I want to make two pipes between 3 child processes, but I firstly want to get the first pipe `pipe1` working between two fork processes. The problem is that when i dup the stdout from the first process and likewise dup the stdin from the other process, i don't get output.

```
int main()
{
  int pipe1[2];
  int pipe2[2];
  pipe(pipe1);
  pipe(pipe2);
  sem_t mutex_pipe1;
  sem_t mutex_pipe2;
  sem_init(&mutex_pipe1, 0, 0);
  sem_init(&mutex_pipe2, 0, 1);


  if (fork()==0) {           //process 1
    close(1);        /* close normal stdout */
    dup(pipe1[1]);   /* make stdout same as pfds[1] */
    sem_post(&mutex_pipe1);
    execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);       
  }

  if (fork()==0){           //process 2
    sem_wait(&mutex_pipe1);
    close(0);
    dup(pipe1[0]);
    dup2(pipe1[1], 1)      //want to open stdout again.
    sem_post(&mutex_pipe1);
    execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);           
  }
```

Comment: Fyi, neither of those `sem_post` are going to ever see the light of day.  You just `execlp`ed right before them. That call *replaces* the running process image. I.e. there is no spoon. The only way those will execute is if the `execlp` calls *failed*.

Comment: @WhozCraig you're answering OP's question - you should make it an answer so I can upvote it ;)

Comment: Hmm I believed that my semaphores were working, since before I called "dup" on stdin, stdout on pipes, I first got "ls" executed and the process hang for the "wc -l" command I thought?

Comment: @ot0 Don't take my word for it; [see the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp). If the processes are executing successfully, those `sem_post`s are never getting called.

Comment: is my calls to dup correct? The way i change the file descriptors. And thanks for the answer. Im trying out your suggestion.

Comment: Why are you involving semaphores in this at all?  They are not inherently necessary for processes to communicate via a pipe.  In fact, pipes constitute an inter-process synchronization mechanism in themselves.

Comment: Always use `dup2()` if you want to dupe onto a specific file descriptor.  Don't worry about whether the target FD is open; it will be closed first if necessary.

Comment: thanks John Bollinger. I was using Semaphores because I would be sure that the first process ran before second process  due to make redirections on the pipe. But is it unnecessary?

Comment: @ot0, your use of semaphores had *no effect* on the order in which things ran.  Using a pipe for IPC, on the other hand, inherently provides for synchronization with respect to reads and writes, because the reader won't get any data until the writer writes some.  Do understand that not getting data (yet) is very different from determining that no more data will be forthcoming.  You don't need any more synchronization than that for the code presented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your semaphores are not doing anything useful for you in the code you presented.  It's unclear to me what you even suppose they might do, especially once your child processes invoke `exec()`-family functions.

Moreover, you cannot "open stdout again" once it is closed.  You can associate file descriptor 1 (and thus `stdout`) with a different file, but you cannot get back a file once you have closed all the FDs associated with it, except by `open()`ing or `fopen()`ing it again.

However, you seem not to appreciate that after a `fork()`, the child and parent processes do not share memory, at least not in the sense that ordinary memory writes by one are visible to the other.  Thus, in your original code, when the first child closes its `stdout`, the parent is not affected, and the second child doesn't inherit any change or any need to recover the original `stdout`.

On the other hand, be aware that when you `fork()` a child process, and it inherits the parent's open file descriptors, that results in two processes having each of those file descriptors open.  Also, when you dupe an FD, you have a second FD open on the same file.  You need to close *all* of them before the underlying open file is closed, and failing to do so can have unwanted effects.  In your case in particular, your second child process hangs because it's waiting for its `stdin` to be closed on the other side, and although the first child process closes *its* copy, the parent process still holds an open FD on it.  The `wc` program produces no output until it has consumed its whole input.  You would probably see some output if you were instead exec'ing, say, `cat`.

Furthermore, the parent should normally wait on its child processes to complete before exiting itself, and it must eventually wait on them to clean up after them if it continues performing other work.

Finally, always, *always* check return values for error codes.

Here's a pretty minimal version of how to set up a pair of child processes that communicate unidirectionally via a pipe:

```
#define DIE do { perror(NULL); exit(1); } while (0)
#define DO_OR_DIE(f) do { if ((f) < 0) DIE; } while (0)

int main(void)
{
  int pipe1[2];

  DO_OR_DIE(pipe(pipe1));

  switch (fork()) {
      case -1:  /* failed to fork */
          DIE;
      case 0:   /* child process 1 */
          /* make stdout a copy of the write end of the pipe */
          DO_OR_DIE(dup2(pipe1[1], STDOUT_FILENO));
          /* close the excess file descriptor */
          DO_OR_DIE(close(pipe1[1]));
          execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
          /* execlp returns only on failure */
          DIE;
      /* default: parent process */
  }

  /* close the parent's copy of this FD, lest child2 hang */
  DO_OR_DIE(close(pipe1[1]));

  switch (fork()) {
      case -1:  /* failed to fork */
          DIE;
      case 0:   /* child process 1 */
          /* make stdout a copy of the write end of the pipe */
          DO_OR_DIE(dup2(pipe1[0], STDIN_FILENO));
          /* close the excess file descriptor */
          DO_OR_DIE(close(pipe1[0]));
          execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);           
          /* execlp returns only on failure */
          DIE;
      /* default: parent process */
  }

  /* close the parent's copy of this FD, for consistency and tidiness*/
  DO_OR_DIE(close(pipe1[0]));

  /* wait for two child processes to stop */
  DO_OR_DIE(wait(NULL));
  DO_OR_DIE(wait(NULL));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments and valuable time. You have given me information about important details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John Bollinger given the inspiration. The following will be an answer of using three child processes with two pipes executing `ls|sort|less|`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DIE do { perror(NULL); exit(1); } while (0)
#define DO_OR_DIE(f) do { if ((f) < 0) DIE; } while (0)


int main(void)
{
  int pipe1[2];                   //pipe1
  int pipe2[2];                   //pipe2

  DO_OR_DIE(pipe(pipe1));         //initialize pipe1
  DO_OR_DIE(pipe(pipe2));         //initialize pipe2

  switch (fork()) {
      case -1:  // failed to fork 
          DIE;
      case 0:   // child process 1 
          /* make stdout a copy of the write end of pipe1 */
          DO_OR_DIE(dup2(pipe1[1], STDOUT_FILENO));
          /* close the excess file descriptor */
          DO_OR_DIE(close(pipe1[1]));
          execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
          /* execlp returns only on failure */
          DIE;
      /* default: parent process */
  }

  /* close the parent's copy of pipe1 write end. Avoids child2 hanging */
  DO_OR_DIE(close(pipe1[1]));

  switch (fork()) {
      case -1:  // failed to fork 
          DIE;
      case 0:   // child process 2 
          /* make stdin a copy of the read end of pipe1 */
          DO_OR_DIE(dup2(pipe1[0], STDIN_FILENO));
          /* close the excess file descriptor */
          DO_OR_DIE(close(pipe1[0]));
          /* make stdout a copy of the write end of pipe2 */
          DO_OR_DIE(dup2(pipe2[1], STDOUT_FILENO));
          /* close the excess file descriptor */
          DO_OR_DIE(close(pipe2[1]));

          execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);           
          /* execlp returns only on failure */
          DIE;
      /* default: parent process */
  }

  /* close the parent's copy of pipe1 read end, for consistency and tidiness*/
  DO_OR_DIE(close(pipe1[0]));

  /* close the parent's copy of pipe2 write end. Avoids child3 hanging */
  DO_OR_DIE(close(pipe2[1]));

  switch (fork()) {
      case -1:  // failed to fork 
          DIE;
      case 0:   // child process 3 
         /* make stdin a copy of the read end of pipe2 */
             DO_OR_DIE(dup2(pipe2[0], STDIN_FILENO));
             /* close the excess file descriptor */
             DO_OR_DIE(close(pipe2[0]));          
          execlp("less", "less", NULL);           
          /* execlp returns only on failure */
          DIE;
      /* default: parent process */
  }
  /* close the parent's copy of pipe2 read end, for consistency and tidiness*/
  DO_OR_DIE(close(pipe2[0]));

  /* wait for child processes to stop */
  DO_OR_DIE(wait(NULL));
  DO_OR_DIE(wait(NULL));
  DO_OR_DIE(wait(NULL));

  return 0;
}
```